# Models relate in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I hope you are well, I need your help, I am working with Laravel and I need to relate information, I have the User, TypeCost and CostCenter models where relationships are:

```
user:
hasMany ('TypeCost');
belongsTo ('CostCenter', 'id');

TypeCost:
belongsTo ('User');

CostCenter:
hasMany ('User');
```

I have my view index in the TypeCost module, there are loads information from the cost of each user, I need is that if the user logged belongs to CostCenter one simply show records of users who belong in CostCenter 1 and so CostCenter for the 2, 3, etc.

This is my Index method that is responsible for displaying the list of expenses:

```
public function index ()
{
$ type_costs = TypeCost :: paginate ();
return View :: make ('type_costs.index' compact ('type_costs'));
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `compact` instead of `View::make()->with()`?

Comment: Use a scaffold to create a controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
//for user model
public function costcenter()
{
  $this->belongsTo('CostCenter');
}
 //for costcenter model
public function users()
{
  $this->hasMany('User');
}

//controller function
public function index ()
{
  $cost_centers = Auth::user()->costcenter;
  $cost_users = $cost_centers->users;
  return View::make ('type_costs.index', compact ('cost_users'));
}
```

it will return list of users that belongs to CostCenter of logged user.
If the field of costcenter_id in user table is nullable, u can add some validation on controller.

Comment: Thanks for all my friend,I'll try.